# Discord.js ReactionCollector Help Menu - reset emojis

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I am using the below code to create a help menu for a Discord bot.

```
let pages = ['Page one!', 'Second page', 'Third page'];
let page = 1; 

    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed() // Define a new embed
    .setColor(0xffffff) // Set the color
    .setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`)
    .setDescription(pages[page-1])

    message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {

    msg.react('⬅').then( r => {
        msg.react('➡')

        // Filters
        const backwardsFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⬅' && user.id === message.author.id;
        const forwardsFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '➡' && user.id === message.author.id;

        const backwards = msg.createReactionCollector(backwardsFilter, {timer: 6000});
        const forwards = msg.createReactionCollector(forwardsFilter, {timer: 6000});

        backwards.on('collect', r => {
            if (page === 1) return;
            page--;
            embed.setDescription(pages[page-1]);
            embed.setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`);
            msg.edit(embed)
        })

        forwards.on('collect', r => {
            if (page === pages.length) return;
            page++;
            embed.setDescription(pages[page-1]);
            embed.setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`);
            msg.edit(embed)
        })
    })
})
```

}

It works except I have to click twice on the emoji to move to the next/previous page.  I believe I need to remove the emojis and then reload them in their default settings.

Does anybody know the best way of doing this? or if there is something else I need to do instead?

Comment: Thanks DNLST it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=remove

```
r.remove(r.users.filter(u => u === message.author).first());
```

Inside both collectors should do a job.

**EDIT**

If you want every user to be able to use this menu, it's better to use this filter instead:

```
.filter(u => !u.bot)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this and tries using this code on the current version of DJS and gets errors, here is how to write this entire function in the current version of Discord.JS (v12.2.0):

*NB: This assumes you have already passed client, message, and optionally any arguments*

**Edit: made it so that the bot will remove the reaction if user selects ie back button but already on 1st page, or forward button but already on last page**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
let pages = ['Page one!', 'Second page', 'Third page']
let page = 1 

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() // Define a new embed
.setColor(0xffffff) // Set the color
.setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`)
.setDescription(pages[page-1])

message.channel.send({embed}).then(msg => {
  msg.react('⬅').then( r => {
    msg.react('➡')

    // Filters
    const backwardsFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⬅' && user.id === message.author.id
    const forwardsFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '➡' && user.id === message.author.id

    const backwards = msg.createReactionCollector(backwardsFilter, {timer: 6000})
    const forwards = msg.createReactionCollector(forwardsFilter, {timer: 6000})

    backwards.on('collect', (r, u) => {
        if (page === 1) return r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())
        page--
        embed.setDescription(pages[page-1])
        embed.setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`)
        msg.edit(embed)
        r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())
    })

    forwards.on('collect', (r, u) => {
        if (page === pages.length) return r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())
        page++
        embed.setDescription(pages[page-1])
        embed.setFooter(`Page ${page} of ${pages.length}`)
        msg.edit(embed)
        r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())
    })
  })
})
```

Hope this helps anyone :)